# Positioning HTML elements on previous ancentors?

Tags: html, css

How do you position an HTML element relative to its ancestors, that is if we have,

```
<div>
  first div
  <div>
    second div
    <p>P</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If both divs are positioned elements, how do you position the p based on the first div?

Comment: no way, but javascript

Comment: Why would you want this?

Answer (score 0):

You can position an absolute element based on his near relative ancestors, so if you want to position the p based on the first div, you can set the `<p>` element as `position: absolute` and add a class to the first div to have `position: relative`, like:

html:

```
<div class="relative">
  first div
  <div>
    second div
    <p class="absolute">P</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.relative {
   position: relative;
}
.absolute {
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: You misread the question, they already are positioned, which make it not possible to solve without script

Comment: mmm sorry, yes, if is like that, your only way is javascript ;)